# MS ACCESS : Syntax error in FROM Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to have a command button insert data into a new table and at the same time select a record and  update it. I will paste my code below and try to explain my problem.

```
CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO Crew " _
    & "(CrewName,KitNumber,ActionDate,ReturnDate) VALUES " _
    & "('" & Me.AssignCrew & "', '" & Me.AssignKit & "','" & Me.AssignDate & "','');"
Crew.Form.Requery

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Info 'WHERE InvKitNumber = '" & Me.AssignKit & "'"
Set myR = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
myR.Edit
myR!Available = False
myR.Update
Set myR = Nothing

Info.Form.Requery

AssignKit = ""
AssignKit.SetFocus
```

So everything works fine with the insert.  But when it gets past that I get the syntax error and the debugger highlights the "Set mrR = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)".  I have fooled around with leaving out somethings but then I just get different problems.  Basically I am just trying to uncheck the checkbox in 'Info' where the unbound text (AssignKit) matches the same number in 'InvKitNumber'.  Is this the correct way to go about this problem?  I have tried a line of code using UPDATE but couldn't quite figure that out either due to "Too few parameters".  Thanks

Comment: Both your table and form share the same name? Info?

Comment: Yes they do.  I have never had a problem with it though.  Would they need to be changed?

Comment: You didn't keep that apostrophe before WHERE in there did you?

Comment: I changed the tables and forms names just to make it clearer in the future.  And no, I took the apostrophe out.

Answer (score 1):

If `InvKitNumber` is really a number then your `strSQL` should be

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Info WHERE InvKitNumber = " & Me.AssignKit
```

Comment: @a shareef Thanks I changed it.  But Now I get an error for "Too few parameters: Expected 1" and the debugger hightlights the line right under that, the "Set myR=db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)"

Comment: Place a `Debug.Print strSQL` right after you declare `strSQL` and post the output.  The output shows up in your `Immediate Window` (`Ctrl + G` to open the window)

Comment: This is right after the strSQL = "SELECT..."  'SELECT * FROM Info WHERE InvKitNumber = 776002'

Comment: Can you make a query manually with that statement and see if it works?

Comment: Yup the statement works.  Just tried it.  It just is getting stuck at the OpenRecordSet for some reason

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?  Try this `Set myR = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)`

Comment: "Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1."  And thanks for the tip, but it was the same error as I got before when I added dbOpenDynaset this time

Comment: Could you double check `InvKitNumber` exists exactly with that name in your `Info` table?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have the same problem. I tested all solutions and decided to change everything that could have played into it. I reduced my query to `Select * From Index` and I still was blocked by the error.

You may not believe it but I ended up realizing it was the name of the table! Yes, the table's name was **Index** and when I dropped *e* and changed it to **Indx** everything worked out pretty smoothly! Is *Index* a reserved word for Access? I don't know and I'd be amazed if it is as no error was generated when I named the table in the first place.

As your table's name is INFO and it is a common word, I  think you should change the table's name and test the same query with other names as Access seems to like to reserve many words!

Comment: Yes, `INDEX` is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Access SQL. `SELECT * FROM [Index]` probably would have worked just fine. (However, `INFO` is not a reserved word.)